# Making okular notes and comments visible to other pdf readers

Tags: pdf, evince, adobe-reader, okular

Is there a way to make okular comment and reviews for a pdf visible to Adobe Reader and evince?

Comment: What version of Okular are you running and what version of Ubuntu are you on? Okular 0.15 and up with poppler 0.20+ installed supports exporting annotations to PDF.

Comment: Version 0.17.3
Using KDE Development Platform 4.11.5